# $E$ is a subset of $[0,1]$ with positive measure, prove that there exists $x,y \in E$ and $k,n \in \mathbb N$, such that $|x-y| = \frac{k}{2^n}$.

Tags: real-analysis

$E$ is a subset of $[0,1]$ with positive measure, prove that there exists $x,y \in E$ and $k,n \in \mathbb N$, such that $|x-y| = \frac{k}{2^n}$.

I want to prove by contradiction. Suppose to the contrary that for any $x,y \in E$ and $k, n \in \mathbb N$, $|x-y| \neq \frac{k}{2^n}$. Then set $E_n = E +  \frac{1}{2^n}$, and they have to be disjoint with each other by our assumption. What will be the contradiction?

Comment: $2=\mu([0, 2])\geq\mu(\cup E_n) = \sum \mu(E_n) = \sum \mu(E) =\infty $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, $E_n\subset [0, 2]$

From this, $\mu(\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty E_n) \leq \mu([0, 2]) = 2$.

Secondly, since $E_n$ are all disjoint, $\mu(\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty E_n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mu(E_n)$.

Since Lebesgue's measure doesn't change when the set is shifted, $\mu(E_n) = \mu(E)$, and from this, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mu(E_n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mu(E)$.

Finally, since $\mu(E)>0$, the sum is equal to $\infty$.

This leads to a contradiction.

Comment: This shows that we can in fact take $k=1$.

Comment: Actually, there's a more general result which says that $(-k, k)\subset E- E$ for some $k>0$.

Answer (score 1):

In this case notice that the sets $E_n$ are all contained in $[0,2]$ then their union must have finite measure. On the other hand, since they are disjoint (as you pointed out) and translations of E

$$\left| \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} E_n \right|=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty |E_n|=|E|\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty 1=\infty.$$

Since E has positive measure.

Comment: I prefer using measure notations instead of the norm. Anyway, your solution's path seems right.